# how to integrate bootstrap carousel in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a static carousel and want to integrate it to wordpress without any plugin.
my question is how to append my images folder, which has all carousel images inside, to the wordpress dynamically.

```
<?php if(is_front_page()){
    $i=0; 
    query_posts('showposts=3&post_type=post');   
?>
<section id="main-slider" class="no-margin">
    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php if (have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); $i++; ?>
            <?php 
               if(has_post_thumbnail())
                    $url=wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id());
             ?>
            <?php if($i==1){?>
            <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>)">
            <?php }else{?>
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>)">
                    <?php }?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row slide-margin">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <h1 class="animation animated-item-1"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                <h2 class="animation animated-item-2">Fake text</h2> 
                                <a class="btn-slide animation animated-item-3" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs animation animated-item-4">
                            <div class="slider-img">
                                <img src="images/slider/img1.png" class="img-responsive">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.item-->
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
    </div><!--/.carousel-->
    <a class="prev hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="next hidden-xs" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
</section><!--/#main-slider-->
<?php } ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

As you know, the `$url` has not any value.
how can I add/remove images to carousel dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

there are many of way to create carousel dynamic,

- you can create custom post type: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types, upload featured Image or post meta image.
- Integrate options frameworks like: SMOF (Slightly Modded Options Framework)
- You also can create custom setting page with WordPress Back-end: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page

Comment: I prefer to use a custom post type for this. So you can set the image as featured image, and you can easy retrieve all nessesary data. [Generate a Custom Post Type](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) and retrieve data with [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

Comment: @AndyTschiersch. they are just images. they are not posts. how can I add/remove images to/from carousel. I have a images folder in my theme.

Comment: You can still use a custom post type for this, even if you just need an image. It is the simplest way, because you don't have to handle with a different directory.

Comment: You can easily manage by custom post type and many of simple slider plugins or a custom themes use it as a simple integration. here, you can also manage custom text or HTML on images/slides if you want. using Images directory it's a hard code to read all images from directory and print it and also you have to mange it via directory instead of back-end.